# How can I parse this text file into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am parsing a big text file with the following format.

city is city1 in the west coast.

(some lines which are not relevant to me)

......

temperature is 15 degree in winter.

.....

daytime is 5 hours.

....

city is city2 in the west coast.

.... the pattern repeats.

I have used line.startswith() and made a outputline by concatenating the values like :

for line in file:

```
if line.startswith('city'):

   line1 = line[8:12]

if line.startswith('temperature')

   line2 = line[:] and so on.
```

finally outputline = line1 +line2+line3

so it prints one outputline for each city block.

But I understand this is an ugly solution. What I want is a dictionary like this:
{city1:[15, 5], city2:[temperature, daytime] ....}

could you please help?

Comment: Probably use `split()` to get the words into a list and then index that list. But you'll still have to check the first word of that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}
if line.startswith('city'):
    current_city = line[8:12]
    dict[current_city] = []
```

From here you just need to `dict[current_city].append(temp)`, etc.

Loop through your input by identifying the pattern wherein the city category will repeat.

Comment: I was able to parse a large text file with lot of complications based on this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the lines of the text file looking for your cues, then add the values to a dictionary. Each city's values are stored in a list, so you'll end up with a list of city properties keyed by the city name.

```
cities = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    city = None
    city_name = None

    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('city'):
            if city is not None:
                cities[city_name] = city
            city = []
            city_name = line[8:12]

        elif line.startswith('temperature'):
            city.append(line[:])

        elif line.startswith('daytime'):
            city.append(line[:])

        # etc.

# Print the resulting city properties
from pprint import pprint
pprint(cities)
```

You may prefer to use `str.split()` instead of slicing the values directly. You may also be interested in something like [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which are much more powerful for parsing strings like this.

Comment: Fair answer. It just struck me now, rereading the question, that the OP's requested structure is impossible. They also have `daytime` against the key so might need a tuple/list.

Comment: Thanks Zac for the solution and editing. What I want a dictionary with cities as keys and each key is  mapped to a list of values of temperature, daytime etc.

Comment: @ana I've updated my answer to produce a list instead of a dictionary.